# Blank page when NavigationPage is used in Prism.Forms after upgrade to 8.x

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

After upgrading Prism library to version 8.0.0.1909 from 7.x in my Xamarin.Forms project I have a problem with using Navigation Page.

This is the code I have in OnInitialized method:

```
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("AppNavigationPage/MainPage");
```

Now it results in blank screen. It used to work fine. When I don't use navigation Page

```
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");
```

I can see my MainPage just fine.

One additional note, in my MainPage I have following

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var vm = BindingContext as MainPageViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
        vm.OnAppearing();
}
```

When I use NavigationPage, breakpoint doesn't hit there.

I debug it on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was very old code to set starting page. I changed to

```
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Seems to be working now.